# Avoid Repeated File Reading Java

Tags: java, file, methods

After parsing a file, I put everything in Map mainMap. 
The mainMap object is an attribute of a class. All methods in the class access and change this object(e.g element removal).
This leads to reading the file every time before invoking some of the class methods.
Is there a way to preserve(changes within the methods to be not visible outside the methods) mainMap object outside the methods?

Comment: Your question is vague... You need to post some code.

Comment: Would be good to know more about the code. Are you using streams or MappedByteBuffer?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a class level Map instance with a getter, then in the getter something like following:

```
private Map getMap(){
if(map == null)
{
//populate map code
}
return map;
}
```

Comment: Here is the clarification to my problem. I have a Map which is the attribute of a class e.g. Class. Map corresponds to data which are read from a huge file. Now I want to invoke a method from Class for 1000 times. That means I need to read file and put it in the Map for 1000 times, every time before invoking some method. The thing is that methods are changing Map and what I need is a way to prevent the reflection. Every time some method is invoked it should work with the unchanged Map.

Comment: In that case, you can "clone" the original map and provide a copy to each of the method.